# Meteor ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Tags: meteor

I am trying to use the `jalik:ufs` Meteor package to implement file upload but I am seeing this error message when starting my Meteor application:

**Error message**

```
W20151016-15:55:44.251(-4)? (STDERR) /Users/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.z0bbxn++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20151016-15:55:44.252(-4)? (STDERR) throw(ex);
W20151016-15:55:44.252(-4)? (STDERR) ^
W20151016-15:55:44.252(-4)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: _ is not defined
W20151016-15:55:44.252(-4)? (STDERR) at new UploadFS.store.Local (packages/jalik_ufs-local/packages/jalik_ufs-local.js:21:1)
W20151016-15:55:44.252(-4)? (STDERR) at is_admin (packages/mypack_biotools/collections.js:12:1)
W20151016-15:55:44.253(-4)? (STDERR) at /Users/me/Documents/meteor/test/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/mypack_biotools.js:271:4
W20151016-15:55:44.253(-4)? (STDERR) at /Users/me/Documents/meteor/test/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/mypack_biotools.js:749:3
W20151016-15:55:44.253(-4)? (STDERR) at /Users/me/Documents/meteor/test/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20151016-15:55:44.253(-4)? (STDERR) at Array.forEach (native)
W20151016-15:55:44.253(-4)? (STDERR) at Function..each..forEach (/Users/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.z0bbxn++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20151016-15:55:44.254(-4)? (STDERR) at /Users/me/Documents/meteor/test/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

**My application layout is like this**

```
main meteor app dir
--packages
----mypack:biotools
----mypack:manage-users
```

**meteor list**

- blaze-html-templates 1.0.1
- ecmascript 0.1.5
- es5-shim 4.1.13
- jquery 1.11.4
- meteor-base 1.0.1
- mobile-experience 1.0.1
- mongo 1.1.2
- mypack:biotools 1.0.0+
- mypack:manage-users 1.0.0+
- session 1.1.1
- standard-minifiers 1.0.1
- tracker 1.0.9

**other package versions**

- jalik:ufs@0.2.9
- jalik:ufs-local@0.2.2
- Meteor 1.2.0.2

**Package.js for mypack:biotools and mypack:manage-users contains**

```
api.use("underscore@1.0.4");
api.imply("underscore@1.0.4");
```

**Package.js for mypack:biotools contains**

```
api.use("jalik:ufs@0.2.9");
api.use("jalik:ufs-local@0.2.2");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried making sure you have underscorejs installed?

meteor add underscore

Comment: @gdataDan thanks but that doesn't seem to fix it either. The api.use/impy should also install underscore, right?

Comment: Yes and in fact underscore is part of meteor-base, so honestly I'm not sure what's going on with the package. I'd maybe try posting an issue for it on the package's github or contacting the author if nobody here has an answer.